# Node version upgrade npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: BASIC realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"

Tags: node.js, npm

i am trying to upgrade node version to 12.16.1 in my project. after running npm install, i am getting 'npm ERR! code E401' this error

npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: BASIC realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"

this is the exact line console shows.

To make few things clear, i do have npmrc file in same folder as package.json

Comment: Exactly same here. Did you find a solution in the meantime?

Comment: @RahulDole we bypassed it by using npm-force-resolution, maybe you can try that

Comment: I posted my own question earlier and then answered too after I found a way https://stackoverflow.com/q/61613797/1047337

Answer (score 3):

try this one:

- make sure npm login to the registry, to generate the bearer token in npmrc
- On nexus Realms, add NPM Bearer Token Realm

See notes with screenshot https://github.com/s50600822/Notes/blob/main/Nexus/NPM/Readme.md