# npm error E401: Unable to authenticate, need: BASIC realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I upgraded node version to 12.16.2 and npm version to 6.14.4. After that I am not able to run `npm install`, as I'm getting this error

```
 code E401
 npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: BASIC realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"
```

I even tried deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and running npm install again, but doesn't change anything.

Comment: One positive update: I tried again using the auth code of a teammate in the npmrc file and it worked! However others in the team face the same issue as me and after we checked in the nexus account, all of us apparently have the same user access level. Somehow it's working only for one user.
But at least it is confirmed now that it's happening due to the auth code.

Comment: I think you should add your ~/.npmrc to the question

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I had similar issue. I resolved it by adding `_auth` into my `~/.npmrc`. See the [doc how to encode your nexus credential](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager2/node-packaged-modules-and-npm-registries#NodePackagedModulesandnpmRegistries-EncodingCredentialsonLinux). I added the encoded credential using `npm config set _auth xxx`.

You wont be able to see the value using `npm config list` or `npm config get _auth`.

Comment: with nvm 16, `npm config set _auth xxx` creates two entries, one for `:username` and the other one for `:_password`; I don't know why, but if you write _auth directly in .npmrc, it doesnt' work.

Answer (score 18):

In my case, the problem was I've entered another registry address in same Nexus for `npm login` command.

```
npm login --registry=http://nexus_url:port/repository/wrong_address
```

My problem was solved by logging into correct address:

```
npm login --registry=http://nexus_url:port/repository/correct_address
```

Comment: My case is when I run npm login it points to the wrong address =]]]

Comment: this does not work for the nexus username: password case.

Answer (score 17):

You can remove package-lock.json .. it works with me

Comment: that is the safest option. it worked for me too.

Comment: very first attempt you can try this, as this had worked for me

Answer (score 13):

what worked for me is :

I deleted the .npmrc file under C/users/ folder.
and ran npx vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc  command to create a new file in the users folder

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 13):

1. Deleted the `.npmrc` file under `C/users/` folder
2. `npm set registry=http....`
3. `npm set _auth=(login:pass in base64):`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Worked, but why? Is the auth expired, any way to turn it off ?

Answer (score 7):

```
vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc -F
```

Is the only solution I found. Make sure to run `npm install -g vsts-npm-auth` before

Comment: Error is while running npm install command itself. Your edit is saying run npm install

Comment: It's different because of -g is installing a package globally, not locally

Comment: could you edit your answer to flag it `windows only`, it yields this error:  line 13: /Users/xxxx/Library/pnpm/global/5/node_modules/vsts-npm-auth/bin/vsts-npm-auth.exe: cannot execute binary file

Answer (score 6):

I found a way out. With this new npm version they are enforcing authentication to access certain packages. We realised we don't need to use authentication for any of the packages we were downloading, hence the auth code we had was unnecessary. So we just removed it and it all worked.

Comment: if you mean a line with _authToken from .npmrc, it worked for me as well

Answer (score 5):

I'm run set's command from the post and add in nexus "Active realms" profile "npm Bearer Token Realm". Links: https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/system-configuration/access-control/realms
My problem was solved.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30495114)

Comment: This needs to get marked as the correct answer as all of the other ones appear to be solving for a different problem then the specific one mentioned in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this error when running an `npm install` that was pulling some dependencies from a non-public registry located on a self-hosted Azure DevOps (AzDo) server.

I had a `.npmrc` file in the project, and a `.npmrc` file in my user profile dir with an AzDo personal access token (PAT) that had allowed access previously. The AzDo UI reported my token as still being valid.

```
PS C:\src\app> npm install
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="{INTERNAL_REGISTRY_URL}", Negotiate, NTLM
```

#### In my case, the solution was to regenerate the AzDo PAT and update the `.npmrc` found in my user profile directory.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was running `npm login`, then entering my Username, Password, and Email to log in to the registry defined in `.npmrc`. I then proceeded with npm installing the packages I needed and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the Nexus Authentication and project I am using requires Node version: 12.8.1.

I was using node version: 16.13.2

I use NVM to install 12.8.1 with `nvm install 12.8.1`
Then `nvm use 12.8.1`

This will now work on my machine and environment.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue while doing `npm i` for a private npm registry. Solved it by removing the `_authToken` parameter from some lines in my `.npmrc` file in my user's root directory:

Before:

```
//registry.npm.example.com/:_authToken=NpmToken.XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX
//npm.artifacts.example.io/:_authToken=NpmToken.XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX
update-notifier=false
registry=https://npm.artifacts.example.io/
```

After:

```
//registry.npm.example.com/
//npm.artifacts.example.io/
update-notifier=false
registry=https://npm.artifacts.example.io/
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are using Node.js version < than 16.

Just update npm

```
npm install -g npm@8
```

This solver the issue.

Answer (score 1):

if the .npmrc file config like this

```
//registry.npm.example.com/:_auth="base64(username:psw)"
```

try this

```
//registry.npm.example.com/:_authToken="base64(username:psw)"
```

Answer (score 1):

After logging in with:

```
npm login --registry=https://some.nexus.com/repository/npm-private/
```

I noticed that the authenticated line in ~/.npmrc contained two slashes:

~/.npmrc:

```
//some.nexus.com/repository/npm-private//:_authToken=NpmToken.aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd-eee
```

The problem was in the `--registry=https://some.nexus.com/repository/npm-private/`, if the last slash is stipped:

`npm login --registry=https://some.nexus.com/repository/npm-private --scope=@xxx` then all works fine:

~/.npmrc:

```
@xxx:registry=https://some.nexus.com/repository/npm-private/
//some.nexus.com/repository/npm-private/:_authToken=NpmToken.aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd-eee
```

Comment: Thanks. The leading slash issue really drives me crazy! (And Nexus should really update their document).

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, and the solution in my case was:

1. Go to Nexus3 admin panel.
2. Navigate to `Security > Realms`.
3. Move `npm bearer Token Realm` to the **active** realms.

It works with Nexus3 version 3.61.0

Answer (score 0):

In my case, npmjs expected a Base64 encoded Personal Access Token in the `.npmrc` file, and I had forgotten to Base64 encode it before pasting it into the user `.npmrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try downgrading the current node version, 16, to 14.20.0.
My steps to fix this issue.

1. Earlier I had configured NODE_HOME under "Environment variable".
2. I removed it.
3. Only configured the path.
4. Created a new folder in the "C" drive and pasted the node files.
5. (System variable)Path = "C:\Node\node-v14.20.0-win-x64"

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue as I had configured my auth through the .npmrc file by adding the below details to it:

```
_auth=xxx
always-auth=true
email=example@mail.com
```

The error was:
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: BASIC realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"

then got resolved after removing underscore (_) from auth in the .npmrc file:

```
registry=https://nexus/repository/qeema-npm-group/
//nexus/repository/npm-group/:_auth=base64(username:password)
email=jane@example.com
always-auth=true
```

Answer (score 0):

We are facing same issue with Github`npm error E401: Unable to authenticate, need: BASIC realm="GitHub"` while installing npm packges via `npm install --force` in react application`React v18,node v16`.This issue got resolved for us when we change git configution.Here are the steps we followed-

1. Inside Credential Manager -Delete all saved/cached credentials for windows user
2. Changing the windows as well as Git credentials in git.config
3. Cloning the repo again
4. always-auth=true - in .npmrc file
5. removed package-lock.json
6. npm install --force

Answer (score 0):

tried all answers, but no success. our project has its own npmrc and npm read exactly this one, but not that from user folder. i temporarily removed project npmrc, instal packeges ant restore file

Answer (score 0):

I tried with git actions. In my .npmrc file;

```
  echo "@***:registry=https://***" > .npmrc
  echo "@***:registry=https://***" >> .npmrc
  echo "@***:registry=https://***" >> .npmrc
  echo "registry=https://registry.npmjs.org" >> .npmrc
  echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${{ secrets.NPM_ACCESS_KEY }}" >> .npmrc
  echo "always-auth = true" >> .npmrc
```

but getting same error for node version 18. But in version 13, npm install works fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
In such case you can try:
changing details in

**1  .npmrc**
My issue resolved by updating the details in this file. So you too can try it, just by editing values:

registry=https://nexus.............../
strict-ssl=false
always-auth=true
email= your email address
_auth=** (** mean details obtained from cmd or browser console.)



**2. Package.json:**
"jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0" not necessary to match this use one that are provided in your error message.


**3. delete pack`enter code here`age-lock.json**
You can delete this file and hit npm install (don't know how helpful this command is but you can try. As this cmd will recreate package-lock.json
```

Comment: Please **format** your text and code appropriately (and separately)