# Github actions getting 401 unauthorized installing private packages

Tags: npm, github-actions, github-package-registry

I'm encountering an issue during my GitHub Actions workflow where the npm install step fails with the following error:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: BASIC realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"
```

I have a release.yml file for my workflow, and I'm setting up my `.npmrc` file with the necessary registry information and authentication token using GitHub secrets. However, I'm still facing this authentication error.

Here's a snippet from my release.yml file:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: latest

      - name: Create .npmrc
        run: |
          echo "@***:registry=https://***" > .npmrc
          echo "@***:registry=https://***" >> .npmrc
          echo "@***:registry=https://***" >> .npmrc
          echo "registry=https://registry.npmjs.org" >> .npmrc
          echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${{ secrets.NPM_ACCESS_KEY }}" >> .npmrc
          echo "always-auth = true" >> .npmrc

      - run: ls -ail
      - run: npm version
      - run: npm install --legacy-peer-deps
      - run: npm run build-web:prod release
```

I've double-checked my registry information and authentication token, but the issue persists. What could be causing this authentication error, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Did you try what has been suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61613797/npm-error-e401-unable-to-authenticate-need-basic-realm-sonatype-nexus-reposi)?

Comment: yes I tried but didnt work

Comment: Hey! I'm facing the very same issue as you, did you manage to solve it?